# Compose Bottom Navigation fills the selected tab with unselectedContentColor before selectedContentColor

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I have a simple Bottom Navigation in Compose. As can be seen, I have set `selectedContentColor` to Red and `unselectedContentColor` to Blue.

```
BottomNavigation(
    backgroundColor = backgroundColor,
) {
    tabs.forEach { item ->
        BottomNavigationItem(
            selected = item.selected,
            onClick = { item.onClick() },
            selectedContentColor = Color.Red,
            unselectedContentColor = Color.Blue,
            icon = {
                Icon(
                    modifier = Modifier.disabledOpacity(item.enabled),
                    imageVector = getIconAsset(item),
                )
            },
            enabled = item.enabled,
        )
    }
}
```

The problem I have is that when an item is selected, for a very short period of time, the item is filled with `unselectedContentColor` and then it is filled with `selectedContentColor`. So when selected, it is filled with Blue and then it is filled with Red.

I have created a GIF with a slow payback speed.

[image]

I found that the reason is due to the `lerp` function inside BottomNavigation class in compose. it takes 300ms to animate between selected and unselected color.

```
@Composable
private fun BottomNavigationTransition(
    activeColor: Color,
    inactiveColor: Color,
    selected: Boolean,
    content: @Composable (animationProgress: Float) -> Unit
) {
    val animationProgress by animateFloatAsState(
        targetValue = if (selected) 1f else 0f,
        animationSpec = BottomNavigationAnimationSpec
    )

    val color = lerp(inactiveColor, activeColor, animationProgress)

    CompositionLocalProvider(
        LocalContentColor provides color.copy(alpha = 1f),
        LocalContentAlpha provides color.alpha,
    ) {
        content(animationProgress)
    }
}
```

Is there anyway to override this behaviour?

Comment: Try to set "alwaysShowLabel" to true in the method. The animation will not occur.

Comment: @AjayChandran This was an interesting idea, but the default value for `alwaysShowLabel` is true, so it's already true. but I can also see in the code that val `animationProgress = if (alwaysShowLabel) 1f else progress`. So there should be no progress animation, but there is.

Comment: Yeah you are right. Have you tried using the same in release build? Because compose is generally laggy in debug build, but the same is working smoothly in release build.